# Is Facebook not presenting all posts?

Tags: facebook

I'm currently using Facebook to do research on the 2012 United States presidential election. More specifically, I am looking at each of the respective candidate's Facebook pages and getting data related to each post, its likes, its shares, and certain keywords used.

My problem is that I can't see every single post on a page. I like each page, and am currently subscribed to "get notifications." I know I'm not seeing certain posts, however, which I know exist - for example, on the Mitt Romney Facebook page, he posts an average of 5 posts a day for the month of October. Before October 10th, however, posts suddenly stop - I know they are there because I remember getting them in my newsfeed, but the next post I can see is in September. I've clicked see all, and am subscribed to everything I need to be. (I believe) Is Facebook not presenting everything that is there, and if so, how do I see everything?

Comment: Try out [QSearch](https://apps.facebook.com/fbqsearch/) on facebook (if you're cool with its Privacy Policy -- I don't care for it saying it needs your email, etc. without saying why).